# Ext.net Button with Directevents to ExtJS

Tags: button, extjs

I have this button in Ext.Net:

```
<ext:Button ID="BtnEliminar" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:BaseLocalizedText, General_BotonEliminar%>"
    Icon="Delete" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:BaseLocalizedText, General_TooltipBotonEliminar%>" Disabled="true">
    <Listeners>
        <BeforeRender Handler="aceleradorTeclado(this, 'click', LocalizedScript.General_AceleradorTeclado_Eliminar, LocalizedScript.General_AceleradorTeclado_Eliminar_Tooltip);" />
        <Render Handler="asignarPermiso(this, 'Eliminar', true);" />
        <Click Handler="GridHandler.eliminar();" />
    </Listeners>
    <DirectEvents>
        <Click Url="~/Terminales/Eliminar/" CleanRequest="true" Complete="GridHandler.refresh()">
            <Confirmation ConfirmRequest="true" Title="<%$ Resources:BaseLocalizedText, General_TituloMensaje%>"
                Message="<%$ Resources:BaseLocalizedText, General_ConfirmacionBorrado%>" />
            <ExtraParams>
                <ext:Parameter Name="Serial" Value="GridHandler.valorColumna('Serial')" Mode="Raw"/>                            
            </ExtraParams>
        </Click>
    </DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

I found how I can crete it in ExtJS, but don't found how can add de DirectEvents:

```
if (validarPermiso('Eliminar')) {
    topbar.addButton({
        id: 'btnEliminar',
        xtype: 'button',
        text: LocalizedScript.General_BotonEliminar,
        iconCls: 'icon-delete',
        tooltip: LocalizedScript.General_TooltipBotonEliminar,
        handler: function () {
            GridHandler.eliminar();
        }
    });

    // Combinaciones de teclado
    aceleradorTeclado(btnEliminar, 'handler', LocalizedScript.General_AceleradorTeclado_Eliminar, LocalizedScript.General_AceleradorTeclado_Eliminar_Tooltip);
}
```

How I can add Direct Events to Button??

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Way to solve it, using [DirectMethod]. Maybe can help others.

```
// Boton Eliminar
if (validarPermiso('Eliminar')) {
     topbar.addButton({
     id: 'btnEliminar',
     xtype: 'button',
     text: LocalizedScript.General_BotonEliminar,
     iconCls: 'icon-delete',
     tooltip: LocalizedScript.General_TooltipBotonEliminar,
     handler: function () {
          Ext.Msg.confirm(LocalizedScript.General_TituloMensaje, LocalizedScript.General_ConfirmacionBorrado, function (btn) {
               if (btn == "yes") {

                    // Si existen un registro seleccionado para eliminar
                    if (GridHandler.eliminar()) {
                         // Realiza el llamado al Controller para eliminar
                         Ext.net.DirectMethod.request({
                              url: GetNewPath(GridHandler.getPathEliminar()),
                              cleanRequest: true,
                              params: GridHandler.getPrimaryKey(GridHandler.getRecord()),
                              success: function (result) {
                                   //Ext.Msg.alert('Mensaje', result);
                              },                            
                              eventMask: {
                                   showMask: true,
                                   msg: LocalizedScript.General_Mask_Eliminar
                         }
                    });
               }
          }
          else {
               return false;
          }
     });
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to figure this out would be to configure your `Button` in markup (or code-behind), then view the Page. The JavaScript configuration script used to render the ExtJS `Button` is available by viewing the html source of the Page (View > Source).

You can then take that extjs configuration script and modify as required.

Another option, and I would recommend this over using a `DirectEvent` is calling a `[DirectMethod]`. You can call the `[DirectMethod]` directly from any client-side event handler and is a bit easier to setup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you add an example of directmethod or a link?

Comment: Plenty of samples in the Ext.NET Examples Explorer, see http://examples.ext.net/#/Events/DirectMethods/Overview/

Comment: With this DirectMethod... how can I send a "DirectEventArgs e" parameter. The function receive it as: protected void ExportVal(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)